# Default permission and ownership in WSL

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, user-permissions

I'm currently in the process of switching from an Ubuntu 18.04 VirtualBox to the WSL.
Everything is up and running to have a complete web dev environment.
Unfortunately, the file permission and ownership is kind of a problem for me right now.

--- Disclaimer---
I know that in a server environment this would be pretty bad and wouldn't be done.
This is just for my local development process and this requirement will stay there.

What I want to achieve is, to have a consistent set of permissions and ownerships within my /var/www (and all below).

- Every element within /var/www should be owned by my shell user, regardless if file or dir.
- Every element should have the group `www-data`so that the webserver user have access.
- Each file should have permission `0664` and each directory `0775`.
- every new element should follow these requirements.

What I researched so far:
If I make a new directory/ file from the shell or within VSCode, my user and group are used.
If I make a new directory from the windows explorer, the ownership is `root:root`. Nevertheless, I also have to figure out how to set default permissions for new objects.

I just want an easy to use way to CRUD my files from anywhere I am on my system.

Is there anyone with an idea for this?

Thanks a lot, Danaq.

Edit: It would also be ok, to set everything to `www-data:ww-data` and add my shell user to the `www-data`-group if the permissions are applied like explained above.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1451#issuecomment-536724227), newer versions of the Remote-WSL server, when they get started will execute (if present):

- `~/.vscode-server/server-env-setup`
- `~/.vscode-server-insiders/server-env-setup`

[(more on that)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_advanced-environment-setup-script)

So a solution is to execute:

```sh
# this will affect folders created from the editor
mkdir -p ~/.vscode-server/ && echo "umask 002" >> ~/.vscode-server/server-env-setup
mkdir -p ~/.vscode-server-insiders/ && echo "umask 002" >> ~/.vscode-server-insiders/server-env-setup

# this will affect folders created from terminals
echo "umask 002" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone encountering the same issue and find this question:

Under `~[USER~/.profile` I uncommented the `umask`-property and set it to `002`.
This will, according to this [guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html), set all new created file to `0664` and all new directories to `0775`.

I then added the `www-data`-user to the group of my shell-user with

`sudo usermod -a -G www-data [GROUP]`.

So now, every file I'm creating is owned by and within the group of my shell user. But it can be red by the `www-data`-user too. This should lead to not always using the

`find ./ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`

the command to set the right permissions on all directories of a web project after migration for example.

This solution does only help, if the files and directories are created from the WSL-bash. If you are using the explorer or trying to create a file from the VSCode-terminal, the default umask of `022` will be still applied.