# set umask for VSCode WSL terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

after I solved my issues with different users and default permissions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250668/default-permission-and-ownership-in-wsl/60250985#60250985) 
I'm still searching for a solution to use the same umask within my vscode terminal.

In WSL my umask is set to `002` within `~/.profile`. Using the WSL-console it all works fine.
Instead, echoing umask in vscode terminal (using remote-WSL-extension) returns `0000`. Every file or directory created from within vscode via remote-terminal ends up having `777`.

I already found this issue on github  related to the extension: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1451
Unfortunately the script `~/.vscode-server/server-env-setup` does not do anything. It only contains `set umask 002` which should be correct bash-script and it is set to `777`.

Even deleting everything within `~/.vscode-server/bin/*` and letting the server reinstall itself did not help.

Does anyone have another idea?